# PHP array to Highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

How can I get this data from an array to Highcharts?

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Date
            [1] => data1
            [2] => data2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2015-03-26 02:00
            [1] =>      1,425
            [2] =>     39,294
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2015-03-26 03:00
            [1] =>      1,422
            [2] =>     39,076
        )
```

I'm new to PHP, and in search of a way to get the 1st key (the date) as the x-axis, and key2 (data2) as the y-axis. Could it be done by select all the key values in the array, and pass it to this javascript for Highcharts?

```
$(function () { 
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'line'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Chart Title'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: //Dates here 2015-03-26 02:00//
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'a text here'
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'data1',
                    data: // key1 from array 1,425 //
                }, {
                    name: 'data2',
                    data: // key2 from array 39,294 //
                }]
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array
(
    array
    (
        "Date",
        "data1",
        "data2"
    ),
    array
    (
        "2015-03-26 02:00",
        "1,425",
        "39,294"
    ),
    array
    (
        "2015-03-26 03:00",
        "1,422",
        "39,076"
    )
);

$series = array();

// Get the items of the first array
$items = $data[0];

foreach($items as $itemIndex => $value)
{
    // Skip the 'Date'
    if (!$itemIndex)
        continue;

    // We should have the actual array to add to the 'data', if not skip
    if (empty($data[$itemIndex]))
        continue;

    $series[] = array
    (
        "name" => $value,
        "data" => $data[$itemIndex]
    );
}

echo json_encode($series);
```

Comment: Thanks, how would you put the name and data array fields into the javascript?

Comment: The name is in series array, could you specify which name you would like to add?

Comment: I updated my first post. I would like to pass the date to xAxis, and data1 to the first series. data2 to the second series.